# Laravel 3 Table Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

Can anyone help me how to display the product name? I have productquantity stored in my purchase record and now I want to display the product name in productquantity record.

I have 3 Tables

Purchaserecord

- id
- purchasenumber
- prodquantityid

Productquantities

- id
- prod_id

Product

- id
- productname

**Controller:**

```
public function createpurchase(Request $request)
{
        $purchasenumber = $request->purchasenumber;
        $dataPurchaseRecord = Purchaserecord::where('purchasenumber','=',$purchasenumber)->with('productquantity')->get();
        return view('admin.createpurchase',compact('purchasenumber', 'dataPurchaseRecord')); 

}
```

**View:**

```
@forelse($dataPurchaseRecord as $Request)
              <tr>
                <td> <a class="name">{{$Request->productquantity->prod_id}}</a></td>
                <td><em class="productprice">{{$Request->quantity}}</em>  </td>
                <td style="width:100px;" class="td-actions"><a href="javascript:;" class="delete-modal btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-id="{{$Request->id}}" ><i class="icon-minus"> </i>Remove</a> </td>
               </tr>
               @empty
               <tr><td colspan='4'><em>No Data</em></td></tr>
              @endforelse
```

**Model:**

```
 public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTO('App\Product', 'prodquantityid', 'id');
}
```

`{{$Request->productquantity->prod_id}}` should be display the product name instead of the id 
How can I build the model and view on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your models as

```
Class Purchaserecord extends Model{

    public function productquantity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Productquantities', 'prodquantityid');
    }
}

Class Productquantities extends Model{

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'prod_id');
    }

    public function purchaserecords()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Productquantities','prod_id');
    }
}

Class Product extends Model{

    public function productquantities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Productquantities','prod_id');
    }
}
```

Now eager load your data like

```
$dataPurchaseRecord = Purchaserecord::where('purchasenumber','=',$purchasenumber)
                                    ->with('productquantity.product')
                                    ->get();
```

In loop you access product object as `$Request->productquantity->product->name`

[**Eloquent: Relationships**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)